# Add header to spreadsheet while creating spreadsheet using Google spreadsheet CREATE API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Google spreadsheet API to create spreadsheet using node.js. I want to add an header (having three columns h1, h2, h3) while creating spreadsheet. I am able to create spreadsheet, but I am not able to add header. Any option to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following GAS sample? If you want to run except for GAS, please tell me.

In order to use this, at first, please enable Google Sheet API v4 of Advanced Google services and of Google API Console.

How to use it is as follows.

1. In the script editor, select Resources > Advanced Google services
2. In the dialog that appears, click the on/off switch for Google Sheets API.
3. At the bottom of the dialog, click the link for the Google API Console.
4. In the console, click into the filter box and type part of the name of the API "Google Sheets API", then click the name once you see it.
5. On the next screen, click Enable API.
6. Close the Developers Console and return to the script editor. Click OK in the dialog. The advanced service you enabled is now available in autocomplete.

The detail information is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced.

**Script :**

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.create({
  "properties": 
  {
    "title": "filename" // filename
  },
  "sheets": 
  [
    {
      "data": 
      [
        {
          "startRow": 0, // 1st row
          "startColumn": 7, // column h
          "rowData": 
          [
            {
              "values": 
              [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": 
                  {
                    "stringValue": "sample text h1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": 
              [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": 
                  {
                    "stringValue": "sample text h2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": 
              [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": 
                  {
                    "stringValue": "sample text h3"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

**Result :**

[image]

I'm sorry for being long JSON data. Please change the sample text. If you want to use a number for the cell, please use `"numberValue"` instead of `"stringValue"`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

**Added 1 :**

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange('h1:h3');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('protected');  
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
```

Above script protects `h1:h3`. Owner can edit all cells, but other users cannot edit only `h1:h3`.

**Added 2 :**

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.create({
  "properties": 
  {
    "title": "filename"
  },
  "sheets": 
  [
    {
      "protectedRanges": 
      [
        {
          "range": 
          {
            "startColumnIndex": 7,
            "endColumnIndex": 8,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 3,
            "sheetId": 0
          },
          "description": "protected",
          "editors": 
          {
            "users": 
            ["your e-mail address"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "data": 
      [
        {
          "startColumn": 7,
          "startRow": 0,
          "rowData": 
          [
            {
              "values": 
              [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": 
                  {
                    "stringValue": "sample text h1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": 
              [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": 
                  {
                    "stringValue": "sample text h2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": 
              [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": 
                  {
                    "stringValue": "sample text h3"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "properties": 
      {
        "sheetId": 0
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

This script create new spreadsheet. At that time, it adds data to 'h1:h3' and protects them. Please add your e-mail address as the editor. This is used Google Sheet API v4.

Comment: it's really helpful! Thank you so much. Could you also let me know how to make these three values H1, H2, H3 non editable while creating the sheet?

Comment: You can use Class Protection. You can see the detail here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

Comment: I think this reference will help me, but I am not able to find where this SpreadsheetApp class comes from and how to integrate it in above code. Can you please help me?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it. By the added script, users except for owner cannot edit only ``h1:h3``.

Comment: My problem is where does SpreadsheetApp class come from?? and where to put the code you added in my code?

Comment: You can check the detail information about 
Class SpreadsheetApp. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app You can get the effect of the added sample script by running it as a new function.

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing you over and over again, but I already seen that detail information about Class SpreadsheetApp. Only thing is that I dont know how to include it in my above code? If I include it simply it says undefined SpreadsheetApp. I am not getting any clarity. That's why I am asking you.

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. You can use the scripts of my answer as a function. Although I have never seen your script, you can get the effect by reflecting the script with the flow and parameters of my answer to your script. Please don't worry because I have confirmed the executed results by my self, again.

Comment: It's ok. What I am asking is how do you get this class SpreadsheetApp. Because in my code it says SpreadsheetApp is undefined. I have used your first piece of code and adding your today's code at the end of it.

Comment: I updated my answer as added 2, just now. Please check it. Since I could know that you have used my first one, I propose this.

Comment: Hi  Tanaike, I am trying to make the sheet publically available at the time of creation, so that others don't have to take permission to edit it. Do you have any idea how to do it in this existing code?

Comment: When spreadsheet creates using Sheet API, it cannot give permission, simultaneously. So if you want to create spreadsheet and give permission to it, you can achieve by using Sheet API and Drive API. You can see the detail information here. https://developers.google.com/sheets/ and https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: var fileId = 1EJ1315wg4Llsyg5eyNmjqiX6ZX3U_G8_h8mbSiGHKGY;
 var userPermission = {'type': 'user', 'role': 'writer', 'emailAddress': 'siddharthsogani22@gmail.com'} var drive = google.drive({ version:'v3',auth: auth});drive.permissions.create({resource: userPermission, fileId: fileId, fields: 'id', },function(err, resp) {if (err) {} else { var domainPermission = {'type': 'domain','role': 'writer','domain': 'gmail.com'}; drive.permissions.create({ resource: domainPermission,  fileId: fileId, fields: 'id',}, function(err, resp) {if (err) {} else {console.log('Permission ID: ', resp.id);} }); });

Comment: I am using above code to change permission. But it is saying { Error: File not found: 1EJ1315wg4Llsyg5eyNmjqiX6ZX3U_G8_h8mbSiGHKGY.}

Comment: Can you ask it as new question? Because that is other question. It is difficult for other people to see the script in the comment.